# Comparing Arrays and Return Statement

Tags: java, arrays, return

I was looking for some feedback on a method that I have written. I’m not sure whether my approach is correct. I am trying to write a method that compares if two arrays x[] and z[] are identical in that, every array position f has the same composition (up, down, flat) based on the definitions below. I would like to return true if they are identical and false otherwise. I can assume that my arrays are identical in length.

Definitions:

The value of an array position f is considered up 
`if x[f] < x[f + 1]`

The value of an array position f is considered down `if x[f] > x[f + 1]`

The value of an array position f is considered flat `if x[f] == x[f + 1]`

For Example:
Int x = [1,2,1,2,1,2]  Composition = up, down, up, down, up

Int f = [3,6,1,5,2,5] Composition = up, down, up, down, up

Should return true

For Example:
Int x = [1,2,1,2,1,2]  Composition = up, down, up, down, up

Int f = [3,6,1,5,2,1] Composition = up, down, up, down, down

Should return false

```
public boolean sameComp(int[] x, int[] f) {
    if (x.length <= 1 && f.length <= 1) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
        if (x[i] < x[i + 1] && f[i] < f[i + 1] || x[i] > x[i + 1] && f[i] > f[i + 1] || x[i] == x[i + 1] && f[i] == f[i + 1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There is also Code Review Stack Exchange, have you considered posting it there?

Comment: I had never heard of this but will try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach has two problems;

1. The parameter validation is insufficient, if the length of f is < that of x, you will get a ArrayOutOfBoundsException.
2. You cannot return true as soon as you find an array position that satisfies your test. It would be better to invert the test and return false as soon as you find an array position that fails your test. Then at the end of the loop, just return true.

As a matter of style, that test inside your loop is messy and hard to tell what it's doing at a glance, too much duplicated tests.
I'd refactor the basic 'direction' test into it's own function like this:

```
public boolean sameComp(int[] x, int[] f) {
    if (x.length <= 1 && f.length <= 1) {
        return true;
    }
    if (f.length < x.length) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
        if (direction(x,i) != direction(f,i)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private int direction(int[] a, int i) {
    if (a[i]<a[i+1]) return -1;
    if (a[i]>a[i+1]) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```